# Xamarin iOS getting duplicate data for each UITableView section

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MvvmCross for my Xamarin iOS project. For my tableview source I have say, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h records and section(header): 0 of suitable view has 3 records and section: 1 had 4 then

**Expected result**

Section-0
a
b
c
Section-1
d
e
f
g

**I'm getting:**
Section-0
a
b
c
Section-1
a
b
c
d

The records are being duplicated. I checked the source but source has correct data.

**ISSUE:**

At the end of each section the source is restarting from the top again to fill the records

My source:

**View:**

```
base.DoBind();
            var source = new TableSource<string> (Table, ViewModel);
            Table.Source = source;
            Table.ReloadData();
            Table.AlwaysBounceVertical = false;
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<View, ViewModel>();
            set.Bind(source).To(vm => vm.CardsList);
            set.Apply();
```

**Cell:**

```
protected override void DoBind()
        {
            var set = this.CreateBindingSet<Cell, ListViewModel>();
            set.Bind(LblNum).To(vm => vm.CardNumber);
            set.Bind(Balance).To(vm => vm.Balance);
            set.Apply();
        }
```

**CellViewModel**

```
public class ListViewModel : MvxViewModel
    {
        private string _CardNumber;
        public string Number
        {
            get { return _Number); }
            set { _CardNumber = value; }
        }

        private string _Balance;
        public string Balance
        {
            get {  _Balance; }
            set { _Balance = value; }
        }
```

Can anyone please advice how to resolve this

**Update**

```
    UITableView _tableView;

            public TableSource(UITableView tableView, object item) : base(tableView)
            {
                this.viewModel = item as ViewModel;
                this._tableView = tableView;

                tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(HeaderCell.Nib, HeaderCell.Key);      tableView.RegisterNibForCellReuse(UINib.FromName(Cell.Key, NSBundle.MainBundle), Cell.Key);
                tableView.RegisterNibForHeaderFooterViewReuse(UINib.FromName(HeaderCell.Key, NSBundle.MainBundle), HeaderCell.Key);
                tableView.ReloadData();

                var DataDic = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
                {
                    { "section1", new List<string> {}},
                    { "section2", new List<string> {}},
                    { "section3", new List<string> {}}
                };

                //create the data
                var list = new List<TableModel<string>>();
                foreach (var section in DataDic)
                {
                    var sectionData = new TableModel<string>()
                    {
                        Title = section.Key
                    };
                    foreach (var row in section.Value)
                    {
                        sectionData.Add(row);
                    }

                    list.Add(sectionData);
                }
                TableItems = list;

            } 
public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
        {
            return TableItems.Count;
        }

        public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
        {
            int result = 0;
            if (section == 0)
            {
                result = viewModel.NumOfGiftCards;
            }
            else if (section == 1)
            {
                result = viewModel.NumOfRewardsCerts;
            }

            return result;
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            return section == 2 ? 0f : 74f;
        }

        public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            return indexPath.Section == 2 ? 95f : 62f;
        }

        public override IEnumerable ItemsSource
        {
            get
            {
                return base.ItemsSource;
            }
            set
            {
                base.ItemsSource = value;
                _tableView.ReloadData();
            }
        }

        public override UIView GetViewForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
        {
            var header = tableView.DequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(HeaderCell.Key) as HeaderCell;
            return header;
        }

        protected override UITableViewCell GetOrCreateCellFor(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath, object item)
        {
            var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(Cell.Key, indexPath) as Cell;

            return cell;
        }

        public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            viewModel.CardDetailsCommand.Execute(null);
        }
```

Comment: Can you show where you are checking which section is being loaded? It looks like you are just reloading the array. You need to specify what goes in which section.

Comment: If in section 1 you are getting 4 items but they are the wrong 4 then `RowsInSection` is working but `GetItemAt` is wrong. could you post the code for your `MvxTableViewSource`?

Comment: @Siriss I am using dictionary and just adding header from there and loading cells from source

Comment: @IainSmith Just posted MvxTableViewSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `ItemSource` you are binding the `CardsList` to is not matching up to the `TableItems`, `viewModel.NumOfRewardsCerts` or `viewModel.NumOfGiftCards` that you are using the table source.

Have you had a looked at the [MvxExpandableItemSource](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/MvvmCross-iOSSupport/MvvmCross.iOS.Support/Views/MvxExpandableTableViewSource.cs) (the sample is [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/TestProjects/iOS-Support/ExpandableTableView)) It can handle 2 dimensional ItemSources:

```
private IEnumerable<TItemSource> _itemsSource;
public new IEnumerable<TItemSource> ItemsSource
{
    get
    {
        return _itemsSource;
    }
    set
    {
        _itemsSource = value;
        _sectionExpandableController.ResetState();

        ReloadTableData();
    }
}
```

It deals with expanding and collapsing the from the headers, see below, but you could disable that functionality and force them to be expanded all the time:
[image]

Comment: It worked well now after tweaking ItemSource. Thank you.